# Vector addition of drone affected by wind

Tags: kinematics, vectors, velocity, relative-motion

I've been struggling with this calculation for around a week and am starting to question whether or not it's even possible.

What I want to do is find the bearing and speed a drone will need to fly at to reach a destination, accounting for wind. I think the issue is I don't have enough information.

I have:

Wind speed and bearing

Desired path of drone

Maximum speed of drone

If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be a big help.

Comment: FYI: That's the same problem that airplane pilots used to solve with this thingy: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E6B Google for "electronic E6B" to find what some pilots use these days.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I've seen these used as a possible solution before, however the issue is I don't know the true airspeed. I'm trying to plan routes for drones to take before any of them have left the start point. As far as I can tell E6B won't work without this information.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I stand corrected! I didn't realise they used actual wind speed as opposed to relative wind speed. This solves my problem! Thanks very much